# Get Node by Name from Nodelist

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying to get the node by its name instead of by its index via `item(i)` because the `Document` I'm reading won't always have the nodes in the same place every time but the names of the nodes will always be the same. I'm trying to get the node `<reference>`

So far I have:

```
System.out.println("Current Reference: " + 
    configurationDocument.getElementsByTagName("Parent").
        item(0).getChildNodes().item(0));
```

The problem with this is that the last `item(0)` always gets the wrong node. How do I get the node by name (`String`) instead of by `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XPath to get the node that you are intrested in. Something like this:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression xpr = xpath.compile("//Parent/name-of-item/name-of-item");
System.out.println(xpr.evaluate(configurationDocument, XPathConstants.STRING));
```

Comment: Bummer, that's your configurationDocument, updated the answer

Comment: +1 Nice use of xPath, just beware, it can be slower then simply iterating through the document :P