# How to get a particular DOM node calling by name on the NodeList (Not in XPath) in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

Here I have mentioned in below the way that we are normally working on the Dom nodes.
I want to find a way to get particular node calling by name without iterating over the entire list as I commented on the code.

```
        NodeList                nodeList                = _myDoc.getElementsByTagName("Parent");

        // I want to get child2 node here calling by name without iterating over entire list

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);               

            if (node.getLocalName() != null) {

                if (node.getLocalName().equals("child1")) {

                    // get node as child1

                }else if (node.getLocalName().equals("child2")) {

                    // get node as child2

                }etc...
            }

        }
```

Note : I know that this can be done with XPath. But I'm looking for a way in DOM 
Here NodeList means org.w3c.dom.NodeList and Node means org.w3c.dom.Node.
(Answer in [Get Node by Name from Nodelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891992/get-node-by-name-from-nodelist) provides the XPath solution)

Comment: XPath works really nicely with DOM, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966127/xpath-and-java-with-repeated-tags/12967878#12967878) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088599/xpath-to-select-all-nodes-in-document-with-specified-name-in-java/20088965#20088965)

Comment: Is it? You mean I can pass DOM NodeList to XPath and get a DOM node?

Comment: Okay, sorry, you're trying to pass a `NodeList`, may bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MadProgrammer said, This can be easily done with XPath if you are passing a Node.
So, in my case I passed the Parent Node / Document that I took to derive the NodeList as follows.

```
 Node node = (Node) XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(stringXPathExpression).evaluate(nodeOrDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

To get a String :

```
String  currencyCodeInTotal = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(stringXPathExpression).evaluate(node);
```

Reference :
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/